# How to count only number of "Page" elements in Kentico

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I'm building Bootstrap 3 menu webpart and I need to count the number of child elements. The code below does that, but unfortunately counts all elements (hidden, containers, etc...). I need to count only "Page" elements, or at least elements that I have unchecked from being listed in the main menu.

```
<%# IfCompare(Eval("NodeChildNodesCount"),0,"class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' ","") %>
```

Is there any way I could improve the code above to filter out all that is not a "Page" menu item?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a nested repeater which would only load the Page menu item below the selected section in the menu.
You could then provide the list item in the item template to match your CSS.